# How to catch the range picker button click events and apply a simple transformation to the data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, anychart, anychart-8.2

In this [Range Selection section and examples](https://docs.anychart.com/Stock_Charts/Range_Selection) it shows how to add range picker buttons (10D, 1M, 3M, YTD, 1Y, 2Y, 5Y, and MAX) to the stock plot. See the example from that documentation in the AnyChart Playground [STOCK_Range_Selection_01](https://playground.anychart.com/docs/v8/samples/STOCK_Range_Selection_01).

In my use-case I am comparing prices for multiple funds and I would like to catch the event when any of the ranges is clicked e.g. YtD, then transform the prices for all active series and re-scale them to start from 1. so that the different prices are comparable performance-wise starting at that new X origin. Basically I would have prices1, prices2 and prices3 and divide each by its respective starting price so they become a comparable wealth index starting on that new X origin and with price value of 1.0 e.g.

```
price1.loc[YtD, :] = price1.loc[YtD, :] / price1.loc[YtD] 
// note that price1.loc[YtD] == 1.0
```

How can I do that using AnyChart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the desired behavior, you could use the `getElement()` method as shown below.

```
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
  var dataTable = anychart.data.table();
  dataTable.addData(get_dji_daily_short_data());

  var mapping = dataTable.mapAs({value: 1});

  var chart = anychart.stock();

  var plot = chart.plot();
  plot.line(mapping);

  var rangeSelector = anychart.ui.rangeSelector();

  chart.title('Get element');
  chart.container('container');
  chart.draw();

  rangeSelector.render(chart);

  // Get element.
  var button = rangeSelector.getElement();
  
  // use a listener to trigger your code
  button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    alert(event.target.innerHTML);
  });
});
```

You could also take a look at the [sample](https://playground.anychart.com/OYX01LsQ) we've created on our playground.

Comment: thanks a lot! this was very helpful!! as a follow up question .. how can I capture if there is any change to the viewport of the plot? for example, suppose I alter the prices upon a click which you nicely shown in the answer; but then I need to bring the prices to its original values upon, for example, dragging the time period slider.